# Using Workspace To Raster Dataset tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, merge

I am going to use the "Workspace to raster dataset" tool to merge several tif files. I have 4 test images (same area, same geographic, just different in time).

The input workspace has been set up, it is a folder with four images.
The target Leicester dataset was used after copying and renaming one of the four images.

I set "Mosaic" to "MEAN" and "Mosaic colormap Mode" to "Match" among the options. In this setting, I think that output Leicester's one arbitrary grid should be the average value on the same grid as the four images I entered. However, output was not the average of the four images entered. I've tried everything, changing all the options.

I knew this would create Leicester with the average value of the Leicester I entered. What is the problem?

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to get here as a result, you say you have 4 images that have the same extent and you want to average them, is that right? If that's the case perhaps a tool like Cell Statistics http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000007q000000 would be more appropriate.

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.  Here it looks like you may be re-asking a question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278433/combining-multiple-raster-files-into-single-one-using-arcgis-desktop) instead of editing the original so that it can be re-opened and answered.  I often vote to close such questions as a duplicate.